# TableViewCell mark Cell as Selected

Tags: uitableview, uibackgroundcolor

Is it possible in code, rather than by the user pressing the screen, to mark a particular cell as being selected?

As you are probably aware the Cells remember their individual background colour and revert to that original colour once they have been superseded/deselected. I need to mark a specific row as selected when a particular TableView loads as it is coming over from a previous screen and wanted to make sure the same cell is highlighted.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `UITableView`'s `selectRowAtIndexPath:...` instance method.

```
-[UITableView selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:]
```

With this, you can programmatically select any cell. [More info in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath%3aanimated%3ascrollPosition%3a). It's worth noting that there is a matching deselection method.

Comment: Looks likely - will investigate tomorrow and report back - many thanks.

Comment: Works a treat, put this code into cellForRowAtIndexPath [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:recordNumber inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
Many thanks.